# Regarding Text Field Not Changes Value In Iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I am Confusing with text field. I add the text field on table every table cell and when i am insert some value on any text field it reflects on the other text field but when i am scroll and go on the last text field then if i inserted some text in that text field then it is not reflected on the text field. If any one knows about this please tell me

Thanks.

Comment: You could increase the probability of getting useful answers by adding the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I guess you didnt understand the reusing logic of the tableview. Read the documentation about TableViews and `dequeueReusableTableViewCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the cell allocation, in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Unproper allocation / or release of custom cell will create such problem. I faced it before.

You can try the code like this,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//your custom cell class object
    customCell *cell= (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
             cell=[[[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

  //Here you can add your textfield. You can give tags to individual textfield to access them in future.
}
```